# При рандомном спавне обьектов, иногда, два объекта спавнятся в одной позиции. Так не должно быть

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d, list, случайные-числа

Есть два списка:

1. Список позиций
2. Список объектов

Скрипт спавнит объекты из списка объектов
в позициях из списка позиций, выбранных рандомно.
А также в скрипте позиция, которая выбралась однажды, удаляется.
Но у меня бывает так, что позиция повторяется и 2 объекта спавнятся в одной позиции.

```cs
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    private int randomNumber;
    public GameObject[] NotePrefabs = new GameObject[3]; 
   
    
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Vector3> NotePositions = new List<Vector3>();
    


    public void Methood()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NotePrefabs.Length; i++)    
        {
            int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, NotePositions.Count);
            Instantiate(NotePrefabs[i], NotePositions[randomNumber], Quaternion.identity);
            NotePositions.RemoveAt(randomNumber);

            
        }
    }


    void Awake()
    {
        NotePositions[0] = new Vector3(9.98f, 1.5f, 0.20998f);
        NotePositions[1] = new Vector3(4.34f, 1.5f, 8.29f);
        NotePositions[2] = new Vector3(-6.65f, 1.5f, 0.66f);
        NotePositions[3] = new Vector3(0.19914f, 1.5f, -9.35f);
        NotePositions[4] = new Vector3(4f, 1.5f, 0.20998f);
        

        NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[0]);
        NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[1]);
        NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[2]);
        NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[3]);
        NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[4]);
        
    }

    void Start()
    {
        Methood();
    }
```

Comment: `NotePositions.Add(NotePositions[0]);` как вы думаете, что делает эта строчка? `[SerializeField]` - что на этом поле в редакторе у вас висит?

Answer (score 3):

Random может генерировать одинаковые числа, никаких гарантий уникальности нет.
Самое простое что обычно делают для генерирования уникальных значений:

1. Заполняют мавссив (или список)  данными
2. Перетасовывают его (методом Фишера — Йейтса или любым другим)
3. И потом просто последовательно достают данные из уже перемешанной коллекции

Comment: Ну новичок я, что поделать пытаюсь как могу